# What to do if bread dough became hard in the refrigerator

Tags: bread

I kept bread dough in the refrigerator overnight covered with wet cloth. The next morning I noticed that my bread dough had become hard and caked up. Please help, what shall I do to soften it. What can I do with that dough? Will my bread be soft if I bake it?

Comment: Did you put it in the freezer or the refrigerator?

Comment: What temperature did you store the dough at and what were your ingredients?

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/47250/67 .  To fix, see my answer on reviving a too-hard sandwich : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/36513/67

Comment: Johanna, I kept in refrigerator, not freezer . .. sorry for the typo ... I then kept got it out and let it come to room temperature, it became normal then :)

Comment: Chris H, I didn't freeze the dough, sorry for the typo & confusion... I had kept it in refrigerator .... :)

Answer (score 6):

I presume that you meant a fridge, rather than a freezer.

Fridges are by design pretty dry, and the best is to cover the dough with some cling film or some other impermeable barrier. (The wet cloth will dry up pretty fast.)

The dry caked surface is just dried up dough, and can be worked back into the rest. (It may need a little bit more liquids, but not much.)

Comment: Ya I meant fridge :) sorry typo:) ... Thanks for replying to my concern.  I kept is out for sometime till it came to room temperature and it was back to normal :)